# Setting probability of getting a random number 1 or 2

Tags: php

Is there a way to set a probability control on getting a random value either 1 or 2? Suppose if I want more than 70% of the time it should be 1 and only 30% should be the chance of getting 2 in `rand(1,2)`. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random numbers with fix probability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572363/generate-random-numbers-with-fix-probability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a number between `1` and `10`, then if the number is greater than 7, return 2, else return 1

```
x = rand(1, 10);
if(x > 7){
    return 2;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

You will have 70% and 30% of chance to get the number you want

Comment: that's a perfectly simple trick.. exactly matching my query.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you generate a uniformly distributed random number and then filter the number with an if?

```
int x,r;

r=rand() % 100;         // r in the range 0 to 99
if(r<=70){x=1;}
else{x=2;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
function yourrand($prob) {
      $r = rand();
      if ($r < $prob) { return 1; }
      else { return 2; }
}
```