# Implementing probabilistic algorithms

Tags: algorithm, probability

What does it mean in terms of implementation when we say we choose something with probability *a/b*? An explanatory solution will be a great help.

Comment: Check this question [Probability Random Number Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016439/probability-random-number-generator) and its answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability `p = a/b` means that from `b` trials you have `a` successes.

You can model it as the following:

```
float p = static_cast<float>(a)/b;
if (rand() < p) { // rand() returns uniform random value between 0 and 1.
    // handle success
}
else {
    // handle fail
}
```

Comment: Note that in case of non-intersected probabilities, you need to define ranges for each one.

Comment: Caution, with a, b integers, a/b is 0.

Comment: @YvesDaoust if a/b is 0 then we will never get into branch for successes and that's expected. If you mean that integer division might happen and only then cast to float will occur, then I didn't added any casts as i thought it to be logical example, not really production code. Do you think i need to add appropriate cast?

Comment: You can bet the the OP will fall in the trap (your code is valid C/C++).

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am more interested in the line of thought that is taken to translate the mathematics to code. a,b belonging to Integers was put from a mathematical point of view. I have removed them now, for from a computational point of view, the answer is Zero. But that is secondary.

Comment: @Yola Could you please explain why is `(rand() < p) ` a success?

Comment: @Aroonalok let's do a concrete example, `b = 10`, `a = 6`, so you have to choose something with probability `p = 0.6`. If `rand()` returns uniform number in range between 0 and 1, then the probability that returned value will be less than `0.6` is exactly `0.6`.

Comment: @Yola Many Thanks. That helped.